# Get URL current all open tab in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I want to make add-on application for chrome browser. In this application I want to get the URLs of all open tabs in my chrome browser .

I want some idea for how to do this using javascript

Comment: Ok, fine. As that's not a question, you don't expect an answer, huh?

Comment: thank you sir . I want some idea how to do this using js

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something along these lines to get all the URLs of all the open tabs:

```
chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {
    var urls = tabs.map(function() {
        return tab.url;
    });
    // do something with urls
});
```

You'll need to add the "tabs" permission to your app's manifest. See [the `chrome.tabs` documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) for more details.

Comment: can i test my code in client side

Comment: @NiroshanRanapathi Chrome extensions always run client-side. If you want to run your extension without uploading it to the store, you can use the ["Load unpacked extension" button](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted#unpacked)

Comment: thank you sir. I will try this